# Add search box to page

Tags: search

Is there a way to display a search box on a page (resembling the google landing page)?

I have tried to create a search page template. However, this doesn't work as all the wp-template styling disappears.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [`get_search_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form) function. For your custom parameters you can add some hidden fields or you can modify the action attribute value.

The following can be considered as your form layout.

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

You can add your own parameters such as tags, etc. by appending the get parameters to the action attribute of form.

Refer some examples below:

1. [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form#Examples)
2. [WP Beginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-search-form-in-wordpress-for-custom-post-types/)

Comment: Thanks.

I must have been unclear in my message.

I do not want a google search. I want the wp search so i can moderate it a little (excluding certain tags etc.). I just want it to resemble the google landing page in the sense that i want a regular page with a search form on it.

Comment: I have modified the answer as per your requirement. Check now.

Comment: Please expand your answer with some examples, not just links